# How do I change RFDuino device name from iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-bluetooth, rfduino

I am writing an application where I am using Core Bluetooth Services. I am stuck at a point where I need to change the name of RFDuino device. i.e. Currently whenever my app starts searching for devices the device shows its name as 'RFduino' I need it to be changed from within my iOS app. And when I search the same device from different iPhone its should show the "New Name". I tried searching the web but din't get any success. Any help will be highly appriciated. TIA

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change some bluetooth device name remotely, but you can do something like this - after connection to device you can write device name on some characteristic and handle name changing on bluetooth device. It's the only way, in my opinion.